# How to extend single div to the next row

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, typescript

We have a container (red), and a child div (blue). On increasing the child div's width, I want the child div to come to the next row instead of continuing on the same row.
This is what is happening now :
[image]

This is what is needed : 
[image]

```css
.container{
  width:100px;
  height:50px;
  background:red;
  position:absolute;
}

.child{
  width:120px;
  height:20px;
  background:blue;
  margin:5px 5px 0px 5px;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

Any solution to the above stated issue will be very helpful :)
Thanks in advance!

Comment: With your html structure , It is difficult to achive that , Why dont you add both divs on same level ?

Comment: How is the width is increasing for child? is that dynamic or you want it to behave differently.

Comment: You could do that with javascript. For instance when rendering the divs, you can compute their width, and if the parent's width is lower than the child's, then you can adjust the child div's height based on your needs.

Comment: @Jai It will be increasing dynamically

Comment: @RomiHalasz Hi, We want the remaining child div to come dynamically to next row and not adjust it to the same row

Comment: You can't do that with a div. All block level elements are **rectangular**

Comment: @DeekshaMulgaonkar You can only achive your requirement by altering html elements and adding js code to check  the height and width. With your simple html it is not possible I think

Comment: 1. Why?
2. You can't change shape of it like this, cause it's not rectangle. 3. If you really want to, you can do it like 3 divs, where take the short one, and from the first one take same long part and make third div, which will be "the rest"

Answer (score 1):

You will **not be able to do that** with a single rectangular div but you can do something like this.
Hope this helps.

This is another solution not sure if it fits in your case.

```css
.parent {
    width: 500px;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, 186px);
    background-color: red;
}

.parent>* {
     background-color: blue;
     height: 50px;
     border: 1px solid white;
     color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
<div class="child">1</div>
<div class="child">2</div>
<div class="child">3</div>
<div class="child">4</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I have already specified it in my first line of answer that its not possible.
And this is one type of solution if its possible in your case.

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea to the bigger picture of your problem. However here is a hackish way to do it using `HTML`, `CSS` and `Javascript`.

What the javscript does is:

1. Get the `width` of the **container** and the **child**
2. Check if the **child** has a higher `width` than the **container**
3. If the above is true, get the `offset` (childWidth - containerWidth)
4. Reduce the **child's** `width` and make it equal to the **container**
5. Create a `div` and give it a `width` equal to the `offset` and give it a `height` equal to the **child**.
6. Append the `div` to the container

```js
var container = document.querySelector('.container');
var containerWidth = container.offsetWidth;

var child = document.querySelector('.child');
var childWidth = child.offsetWidth;

(function() {
  extendDivToNextRow();
})();

function extendDivToNextRow() {
  let offset;
  let secondRow;
  if (childWidth > containerWidth) {
    sliceChildDiv();
    extendToSecondRow();
  }
}

function getChildOffset() {
  return childWidth - containerWidth;
}

function sliceChildDiv() {
  const newWidth = childWidth - getChildOffset();
  child.setAttribute("style", `width:${newWidth}px`);
}

function extendToSecondRow() {
  const secondRow = createSecondRow();
  container.appendChild(secondRow);
}

function createSecondRow() {
  const row = document.createElement('div');
  row.setAttribute("style", `width: ${getChildOffset()}px; height: 20px; background: blue`);
  return row;
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0px;
}

.container {
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  background: red;
  position: absolute;
}

.child {
  width: 120px;
  height: 20px;
  background: blue;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```